# Retrieve all the records with the minimum value in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am practicing SQL queries using a hotel booking database in MYSQL.
There are 4 tables which are Guest, room, hotel and booking in the database.
I want to write a SQL query to retrieve details of hotel rooms which are having the lowest price. There are more than one record with the minimum price and the task is to retrieve all of them and not only one record.

```
SELECT * FROM room ORDER BY Price LIMIT 1;
```

This will give me only one record and I know there are more than one record yet I don't know exactly how many records are there with the minimum price so that I guess I can't use ORDER BY and LIMIT to perform this task.

Following is a part of the table that I want to query.
Table Name: Room.

[image: Table Name Room:]

In this room table, Hotel_No references Hotel_No in the hotel table and the PRIMARY KEY of this table is both Hotel_No and Room_No together.

How do I do this in MYSQL?

Comment: A) Don't scream with ALL CAPS. B) Don't use screenshots for textual data.

Comment: Use text for text. So give the table as text in columns in a code block format. See the edit help. In code questions give a [mre]. So this table should be initialization code that is text in columns in a code block format. [ask] [help]

Answer (score 2):

If you want all records that have the minimum price over the whole table, one cross-database solution is to filter with a correlated subquery:

```
select r.*
from room r
where r.price = (select min(r1.price) from room r1)
```

Depending on your database, better solutions might be available. Typically, SQL Server has `TOP 1 WITH TIES`:

```
select top 1 with ties r.* from room r order by r.price
```

Or, if your database support window functions, you can use `rank()`:

```
select *
from (select r.*, rank() over(order by price) rn from room r) t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM Room t
LEFT JOIN Room t1 ON t1.Price < t.Price
WHERE t1.Id IS NULL
```

This assumes your table has an Id column - if it doesn't you can just use `WHERE t1.Price IS NULL` on the last line.

It returns all records for which no lower price exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the rooms with the minimum price for each `hotel_no` then use `NOT EXISTS` like this:

```
select r.* from room r
where not exists (
  select 1 from room
  where hotel_no = r.hotel_no and price < r.price
)
```

If you want just the rooms with the minimum price:

```
select r.* from room r
where not exists (
  select 1 from room
  where price < r.price
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can try
SELECT *
FROM room
WHERE price =  ( SELECT MIN(price) FROM room )

Answer (score 0):

The earlier answer i gave  works in MSSQL, below will work in MYSQL

SELECT * FROM `room` WHERE price=( SELECT MIN(price) FROM room )

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT TOP 1 hotel.hotelnos, hotel.roomnos, hotel.roomtype, hotel.price
FROM hotel
ORDER BY hotel.price;
```

this might vary depending on the type of SQL, e.g Mysql,MSSQL,etc

Comment: The query i wrote works and will retrieve as many records that have the minimum price

Comment: Yes i wrote TOP 1, and it will retrieve as many records with the minimum price

Comment: Can you please help me understand? Do you see my small demo on the link I have sent in my previous comment ?

Comment: i used the sql statement below SELECT TOP 1 hotel.hotelnos, hotel.roomnos, hotel.roomtype, hotel.price
FROM hotel
ORDER BY hotel.price; and it retrieved all rows with the minimum price

Comment: Try the same SQL statement in vba,ms access and it will return multiple rows. Alter the table definition to have a pkey that is an auto generated key

Comment: vba runs on MSDE which is light version of MSSQL,while MS SQL documentation states that it will retrieve only one row, in VBA,it retrieves all rows with the minimum value

Comment: Read about MSDE on this url, most developers are not knowledgeable about it, its runs on Sql server    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSDE